# Database Query not pulling the full (or correct) information

Tags: mysql

I have been working on a multi-table query (something I haven't had much experience in) and at first I thought it was working perfectly fine until I noticed that half of the results had null values. I have put the query and table structures below so any help would be appreciated!

```
SELECT
  i.name, i.material, i.price, a.str_mod, a.def_mod, 
  a.dex_mod, a.spd_mod, i.level_req 
FROM `character` as c 
LEFT JOIN item_owned as o ON c.uid = o.oid 
LEFT JOIN items as i ON o.iid = i.id 
LEFT JOIN armour as a ON i.id = a.aid 
WHERE uid = :id AND o.equipped = 1 AND i.type = 'Armour'
```

Above is the query I have been running and below is the table structures
[image: Armour talbe]
[image: Items table]
[image: Items Owned table]

Comment: when using `LEFT JOIN` you can expect to see null values in your results.

Comment: As @isaace says the use of `LEFT JOIN` will necessarily produce null (that's its purpose). Change to `JOIN` instead to get rid of null values.

Comment: unfortunately, just doing `JOIN` only returns half the results AND the field `str_mod` is showing 0 instead of 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution thanks to Malfunct on discord... The query had a column typo so should have been

```
SELECT 
    i.name, i.material, i.price, a.str_mod, a.def_mod, a.dex_mod, a.spd_mod, i.level_req 
FROM `character` as c 
JOIN item_owned as o ON c.uid = o.oid 
JOIN items as i ON o.iid = i.id 
JOIN armour as a ON i.id = a.aid WHERE uid = 1 
AND o.equipped = 1 
AND i.type = 'Armour'
```